# Not able to click on an element using xpath

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I tried to click on an element using `CSS selector` and later `Xpath`. But failed both. Can anyone help me in solving the issue. Below is the xpath I provided.

```
Xpath: //*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[3]/div[2]/div/button
```

Html: Select or search a country in the list... Bahrain

I am new to Selenium and don't have prior experience in automating applications. Should I stick on using xpath or should try using some other locators?

Comment: We need to know the exact code of the HTML platform or the website itself. Otherwise, the XPath cannot help us at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Or

Get the `xpath` of the `WebElement`. Put them in the `List` (Java Collection)

```
List<WebElement> lst = xpath ;
for(WebElement we:lst){
    if(we.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Bahrain"))
        we.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Prajith KS Javascript executor or List ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to search for the desired text and click the element.

```
String searchText = "Bahrain"; // you can parameterize it 
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("content"));
dropdown.click(); // assuming you have to click the "dropdown" to open it
List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement option : options)
{
    if (option.getText().equals(searchText))
    {
        option.click(); // click the desired option
        break;
    }
}
```